# getting JSON out of jQuery - from Foursquare API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foursquare

I have not yet found a close enough answer to help me with this. I keep getting [object] as the output, I want the JSON so I can do things with it. Please help me do this correctly. I have tried the documentation for both Foursquare and jQuery, as well as a bunch of YouTube videos, and of course articles here. I am sure it is a simple thing, I just can't see it for being too close.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Blank Page</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>

<script>
var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20161016&ll=34.0707998%2C%20-84.0554183&query=park&intent=browse&radius=2000&client_id=O3VAAPG2MY5H2QERHNM2G03DOKVHN1L1ESUD31251FVEMUXY&client_secret=40B2KAJFL2F5UFSP1WXSBYAM3UPDFI3GAMTBRGC20KIN53YJ";
function getFoursquare(url){
  var new_locations = $.ajax(url);
    return new_locations;
};

$('p').text(getFoursquare());

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not how $.ajax works. Read the documentation and look at the examples. `new_locations` is a promise...not the data

Comment: I added an answer, but FYI if you run your URL in Firefox, it has a wonderful styling applied to the JSON, and lets you see the structure you'll be dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to use the foursquare response, you need to have a json dataType for the AJAX, and you have to let the AJAX handle what happens with the response. To show you how that works, consider the following code. It adds the names of the venues to the paragraph:

```
function getFoursquare(){
  var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20161016&ll=34.0707998%2C%20-84.0554183&query=park&intent=browse&radius=2000&client_id=O3VAAPG2MY5H2QERHNM2G03DOKVHN1L1ESUD31251FVEMUXY&client_secret=40B2KAJFL2F5UFSP1WXSBYAM3UPDFI3GAMTBRGC20KIN53YJ";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var venues = data.response.venues;
      $.each(venues, function(i,venue){
        $('p').append(venue.name + '<br />');
      });
    }
  });
};

getFoursquare();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was just the help I was hoping to get.